# JQuery doesn't select properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to select a button on my page with JQuery and hide it (for now, as a test). For a reason beyond my understanding I can't select it with JQuery, using an alert to test does not work either. Sorry for the messy code, thanks for the help!

**Snippet:**

```js
function mainFunction() {

  document.getElementById("quarter1").innerHTML = 'Welcome to Elements of Art, a website project designed to teach about Art elements for Art Week. <p style="text-align:center;margin-top:25%"><button style="display: inline-block;" target="blank" class="mainButton" id="button1">Click to Continue</button></p>';

  $("#button1").click(function() {
    $("#button1").hide();
  });

  document.getElementById("quarter1").setAttribute("style", "background: color;");
  document.getElementById("quarter2").setAttribute("style", "background: color;");
  document.getElementById("quarter3").setAttribute("style", "background: color;");
  document.getElementById("quarter4").setAttribute("style", "background: color;");
}

function setTopRight(color) {
  document.getElementById("quarter3").setAttribute(
    "style", "background: color;");
}

function mainJQ() {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#button1").click(function() {
      $("#button1").hide();
    });
  });
};
```

```css
#main {
  background: #333333;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
}
#quarter1 {
  background: #006600;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  margin-right: 50%;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-bottom: 50vh;
  position: absolute;
}
#quarter2 {
  background: #003399;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  margin-right: 50%;
  margin-top: 50vh;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
#quarter3 {
  background: #cc3300;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-left: 50%;
  margin-bottom: 50vh;
  position: absolute;
}
#quarter4 {
  background: #cccc00;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-top: 50vh;
  margin-left: 50%;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
body {
  background: #333333;
  margin: 0;
}
.mainButton {
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: transparent;
  border: solid 2px black;
  color: black;
  padding-top: 4px;
  padding-bottom: 4px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body onload="mainFunction()">

  <div id="main">
    <!--The top left quarter of the screen-->
    <div id="quarter1">
    </div>
    <!--The bottom left quarter of the screen -->
    <div id="quarter2">
    </div>
    <!--The top right quarter of the screen -->
    <div id="quarter3">
    </div>
    <!--The bottom right quarter of the screen -->
    <div id="quarter4">
    </div>

  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Are you actually including jQuery? You just completely changed the code around invalidating my answer.

Comment: The demo works, so I think that @divy3933 included your answer when he edited it.

Answer (score 1):

There are many things wrong with your code, so I'll take them one at a time:

1. One of your functions contains the code that should automatically run when the DOM is ready, but that function is never called and it shouldn't wrap the DOM ready function in the first place:

   ```
   // This function is never called, so its child function can't do its job
   // Plus, document.ready shouldn't be encapsulated anyway
   function mainJQ() {
     $(document).ready(function() {
       $("#button1").click(function() {
         $("#button1").hide();
       });
     });
   };
   ```

The code should just be:

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
     $("#button1").click(function() {
       $("#button1").hide();
     });
   });
```

Or, even shorter:

```
   $(function() {
     $("#button1").click(function() {
       $("#button1").hide();
     });
   });
```

Now, you do have this code in another spot on the page, but nested function was never going to run.  Also, make sure that the button hide code comes AFTER the line that creates the HTML for the button in the first place.

2. Every one of your setAttribute calls is wrong. You have:

   ```
   document.getElementById("quarter1").setAttribute("style", "background: color;");
   ```

The second argument for setAttribute should be the value of the attribute you are setting. For example:

```
 setAttribute("style", "background-color:yellow");
```

But, you are setting the `style` attribute to have a value of:

```
 background:color;
```

Which is incorrect.

3. You are using jQuery, so use it in all the spots where it makes your job easier.  Instead of the repeated:

   ```
    document.getElementById
    and setAttribute
   ```

Just use:

```
 $("#ElementId").css("background-color", "SomeColor");
```

4. And, of course, as others have stated, you can't use jQuery unless you reference the library from your code, so make sure you have this:

   ```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   ```

in the `head` section of your web page.

I've cleaned up your code and now the button's dissapearing act works as it should.  See: https://jsfiddle.net/1z3x20aa/29/

Answer (score 0):

Include jQuery before calling any custom code.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Always include **JQUERY library** before the code when using **$()** or **jquery()** method, otherwise use pure javascript.

Comment: This is the same as @SacWebDeveloper's answer.

Answer (score -1):

Try using `.on("click", function(){});` instead of `.click(function(){});`

`.on("click", function(){});` will work with dynamically added content, while `.click(function(){});` will only work with elements that already exist

Using `.on("click", function(){});` will ensure that the function will be run, even if the element doesn't exist at the time you run that line of code.

Comment: But $("#button1").on(...) won't work before the button is created. The selector would have to be more generic, like $("button").on(...)